# How to compile multiple C++ files without specifying each file name using the tasks.json file in VSCode on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-22.04

According to the [VScode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux), you can create a `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder with the `args` field set to `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` instead of `${file}` and it will compile all your C++ files at once, instead of specifying each file individually in the `tasks.json` file.  When I do this I get the following error:

```
/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/*.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

I have two files in the helloworld directory, `helloworld.cpp` and `add.cpp`

My tasks.json file looks this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "My label",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Any suggestions to why I am getting this error? and how to fix it?

I have also tried adding `"${workspaceFolder}/**.cpp"` which gives me the same error. Adding each file name as an argument compiles correctly.

I am using:
Ubuntu 22.04,
GCC 11.4.0,
VSCode: 1.85

**EDIT** changing "type": "cppbuild", to "type": "shell" as in the comments generates this error:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -g "/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp" -o "/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld"
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `main':
/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o:/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: more undefined references to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `main':
/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o:/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: more undefined references to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `main':
/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:15: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:15: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:15: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:16: undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:16: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:16: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:18: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:18: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:18: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o:/home/steve/cpp/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:11: more undefined references to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/include/c++/11/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider::~_Alloc_hider()':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:158: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:534: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_local_data()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:534: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(char*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:212: undefined reference to `std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:219: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:219: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data(char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:220: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_capacity(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:225: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:225: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy_chars(char*, char const*, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:232: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_set_length(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:226: undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:228: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_dispose()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:229: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:226: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_S_check_init_len(unsigned long, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1770: undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::deallocate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, unsigned long)':
/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:145: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
/usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:116: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:117: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:127: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:95: undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:98: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:95: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `void std::_Destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:151: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o: in function `void std::_Construct<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:119: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchaNfwV.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Comment: They have `"type": "shell",`, and you have `"type": "cppbuild",`. I don't know what the latter is for, but the former might be necessary to expand the `*`.

Comment: changing this gives me a new error `ld returned 1 exit status` and modifies my task.json file by adding the type:cppbuild as another task below this one.  But thanks for spotting that.

Comment: The "new error" is more that just that single message. If you can't solve it by yourself then please post a new question about it.

Comment: Please show the entire error.

Comment: I suggest you to invoke cmake or at least make in that launch script rather than trying to solve a problem that is solved by cmake.

Comment: Added the full error

Comment: Your error log shows `gcc` and your `tasks.json` shows `g++`.  Did you change the json?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67236678/775806

Comment: seriously, as said above, why on earth are you trying to use tasks.json to build a project? Unless I'm missing something, you should be using CMake, related VS Code extensions, etc. This works very well, after some setup.

Comment: Because the learncpp.com tutorial instructions say to do it this way and the VScode docs explain to do it this way